# Change default mail language for thunderbird depending on account

Tags: thunderbird, language

When answering mails in Thunderbird, usually a "Re:" or something similar gets added in the subject, and a "wrote on " in the mail itself, citing the received mail. Is there a way to change that to different languages depending on the email account (when using multiple accounts)? I would like to have those phrases in English for one account, and other languages for the others.